# Toggle div = load in content, Untoggle div = remove content

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a page there is a div (#example_div) that toggles a class when click on it using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#parent_div").on('click', '.current_style', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("new_style");
    });
});
```

Below the div #example_div there is a div called `#load_content`.

I want to find a solution to when a visitor click on the `#example_div` it toggles new style just as usually, but at the same time I want to load in some content to `#load_content` from another page. Then when untoggle `#example_div`, the loaded content in `#load_content` removes.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Load content from another page? What exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#parent_div").on('click', '.current_style', function () {
 $(this).toggleClass("new_style");
 if( $(this).hasClass("new_style")) {
    // load content eg: $("#load_content").html("xyz");
 }
 else{
     $("#load_content").html("");
 }
 });
});
```